# Excel VBA ~ Data Table not being written to sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following subroutine:

```
Sub AppendFixedLegData(FloatingLegRows As Long)

    Dim loFixedLegData As ListObject
    Dim i As Integer

    Set loFixedLegData = Sheets("D. Fixed Leg").ListObjects("d_Fixed_Leg_Data")

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("D. PA Data").Range("d_PA_Data").Offset(FloatingLegRows, 0).Resize(109, 247) = loFixedLegData.DataBodyRange  

    For i = 1 To loFixedLegData.Range.Rows.Count
        Debug.Print loFixedLegData.ListRows(i).Range(i, 4).Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

The ‘ThisWorkbook’ statement is not pasting the data contained in loFixedLegData.DataBodyRange, although it *does* execute. What’s more, if I do a Ctrl-End in the worksheet where the data is being written, the Ctrl-End goes to the end cell of the section being written to, proving that some portion of the statement is executing, but no data is being pasted.

I’ve confirmed that the data does exist via the debug.print statement immediately below it.

Why is this not working?

Comment: The range `d_PA_Data` probably isn't the same size as `loFixedLegData`.  Check how many cells wide & tall both are. (Also to clarify: what you're doing is not called **[pasting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel)**)

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the issue...simple in the extreme. There should be a **.Value** at the end of the DataBodyRange, that is, it should be DataBodyRange.Value. Once I put that in, it was fine.